# When you have multiple Members of a Trello card, how to you keep track of who is responsible for the Card?

Tags: trello-organization

To be able to assign Checklist items (and so that users know what Cards they should attend to) I have to add them as a Member.

But if there are several Members on a Card, there is often a [Diffusion Of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility)
And, in particular, if that Card's progress is "waiting" on someone, then it's unclear to *that* person that *they* are the "holdup".

SOLUTIONS
1. Being able to tag someone so they see  *you* are the "next action" (the holdup) on this Card
2. Assign someone to be responsible for moving that Card forward. Then that *owner* would look at the card and see that it's waiting on "Bob" and notify Bob (and flag the card "waiting on".

But I see no way to do either of these.

Answer (score 2):

We use different methods depending on the situation.  Everyone knows ahead of time how to determine who is next.

1. Change the names assigned to the card. The next person listed in the description is now responsible for the card. This is the method our team preferred.  The order is based on who is assigned now.  Harder to keep track of the more people assigned.  Members removed themselves when they finished an item and added the next person in line.  The card description listed the people assigned in order so everyone knew the next name.  In previous Trello versions we could change the order of card members so the first person on the left was currently responsible.
2. Assign each checklist item to a name "Step 1 (@Kevan)" so the next Unchecked item shows who is responsible next.
3. Add the next name in the activity comment.  "@Keavan - Item A completed, you are next"
4. As a group, everyone agreed on what to look for. - When @Brian completes this task @Kevan takes over.  OR - When anyone on the this team completes this task then that team takes over.

I like method 2 for being the easiest to keep track of.
Method 1 used to be like a list order: similar to "Top is higher priority", it was "Left is Next"

Comment: Has anyone attempted to employ custom Labels, with each Label named after a individual Member? Lables are Filter-able, fwiw. What limits does this place on the Trello workflow/process? (I'm a Trello newbie, trying to solve the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Using labels is how I always did it - only just been thinking about using the assigning feature.  So far it doesnt seem to offer enough visibility (especially since Ive been using modified labels, lists and card colors)

Look for a way to highlight the assignee in the same manner as tags.